# R: pairwise chi-squared test comparisons

Tags: r, chi-squared

I need to perform pairwise chi-squared test with correction for multiple comparisons (Holm's or other) in R 4.0.2.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `chisq.multcomp(x, p.method = "fdr")` from `RVAideMemoire` package and
for more detailed information you can visit https://rdrr.io/cran/RVAideMemoire/man/chisq.multcomp.html